# The colour thief

Tags: riddle

I jump from the sky to the ground
Stealing colours from all around
First goes with your sweat and tears
Second is sweet, but has a waxy coat
Last is the flower also known as a pansy

What am I?

Hint:

> I'm gay

Comment: even I got this one! here are some more: http://www.riddlesandanswers.com/tag/rainbow-riddles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are

> a rainbow

I jump from the sky to the ground

> rainbow reaches across the sky and ends in the ground

Stealing colours from all around

> contains all possible colours

First goes with your sweat and tears

> red, the colour of blood

Second is sweet, but has a waxy coat

> orange

Last is the flower also known as a pansy

> violet

Hint

> rainbow flag

Comment: Well done! This was quite an easy riddle, just thought someone would like to hear it. I've heard about you other riddles, Jafe.

Comment: Glad to hear it! The hint was what did it for me :)

Comment: Yeah, I just thought that might be a funny hint to add

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> Rainbow

I jump from the sky to the ground

> The rainbow arch goes from the ground to the sky and back

Stealing colours from all around

> It contains all the colours in the visible spectrum

First goes with your sweat and tears

> blood, sweat and tears - red

Second is sweet, but has a waxy coat

> assuming wax covered oranges

Last is the flower also known as a pansy

> a.ka. viola or violet

hint

> sadly the word for a jolliness was stolen

Comment: Correct but someone answered a minute before you. Well done though.